# Iterating Attendance List in jsp and spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display sutdent name , father name from student table and a boolean flag from attendance table.
I am able to get required list from below query:

```
 List<AttendanceCommandName> studentsList = (List<AttendanceCommandName>) session.createQuery("select     a.studentId,s.studentName,s.fatherName,a.presentFlag from Attendance a,Student s where a.studentId = s.studentId and s.departmentId="+classid+" group By a.studentId").list();
```

Here AttendanceCommandName class contains both Student and Attendance Entity

my jsp iteration looks like this,

```
<c:if test="${!empty studentsList}">
      <c:forEach items="${studentsList}" var="student">
         <tr>
            <td>${student.studentId}</td>
            <td>${student.studentName}</td>
            <td>${student.fatherName}</td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" path="student.presentFlagList" value="${student.studentId}" /></td>
      </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

I am able to get object in `[[Ljava.lang.Object;@6d987577` but with this format
I am unable to iterate in jsp.

Can any body please suggest me in this regard?

Comment: how exactly do you pass studentsList, from controller to jsp?

Comment: @Nithin share your controller handler method

Comment: if student.presentFlagList is a list, is that your problem. Should be a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

In your Hibernate query it returns List of Object array not student list of custom objects so change it to

```
List<Object[]> objList= (List<Object[]>) session.createQuery("select a.studentId,s.studentName,s.fatherName,a.presentFlag from Attendance a,Student s where a.studentId = s.studentId and s.departmentId="+classid+" group By a.studentId").list();
```

iterate this object array list in java and create student list

```
List<AttendanceCommandName> list=new ArrayList<>;
for(Object[] o:objList){
    AttendanceCommandName s=new AttendanceCommandName();
    s.setId=o[0];
    s.setstudentName=o[1];
    s.setfatherName=o[2];
    s.setpresentFlag=o[3];
//type cast above attribute as per your variables
list.add(s);
}
```

now iterate this list in jsp

Comment: Thank you, I had implemented the same as above I am able to display the record can you please suggest me in submission of jsp to mvc controller..?

Comment: i didn't get..what do you want to do..f above answer is correct then please mark it as correct

Comment: Thank you, I am able to display list in my jsp, In the list I had a checkbox  Now I will check some of the checkbox and try to submit the modified list to my spring mvc controller.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `<c:if test="${not empty studentsList}">` instead of `<c:if test="${!empty studentsList}">`